# How can a function pointer replace switch statement?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I am reading this tutorial about function pointers which said that function pointers can replace a switch statement
http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html .

Can anyone clarify?

We have a switch statement like this:

```
// The four arithmetic operations ... one of these functions is selected
// at runtime with a swicth or a function pointer
float Plus    (float a, float b) { return a+b; }
float Minus   (float a, float b) { return a-b; }
float Multiply(float a, float b) { return a*b; }
float Divide  (float a, float b) { return a/b; }


// Solution with a switch-statement - <opCode> specifies which operation to execute
void Switch(float a, float b, char opCode)
{
   float result;

   // execute operation
   switch(opCode)
   {
      case '+' : result = Plus     (a, b); break;
      case '-' : result = Minus    (a, b); break;
      case '*' : result = Multiply (a, b); break;
      case '/' : result = Divide   (a, b); break;
   }

   cout << "Switch: 2+5=" << result << endl;         // display result
}

// Solution with a function pointer - <pt2Func> is a function pointer and points to
// a function which takes two floats and returns a float. The function pointer
// "specifies" which operation shall be executed.
void Switch_With_Function_Pointer(float a, float b, float (*pt2Func)(float, float))
{
   float result = pt2Func(a, b);    // call using function pointer

   cout << "Switch replaced by function pointer: 2-5=";  // display result
   cout << result << endl;
}


// Execute example code
void Replace_A_Switch()
{
   cout << endl << "Executing function 'Replace_A_Switch'" << endl;

   Switch(2, 5, /* '+' specifies function 'Plus' to be executed */ '+');
   Switch_With_Function_Pointer(2, 5, /* pointer to function 'Minus' */ &Minus);
}
```

As you can see, the Replace_A_Switch() function as an example is very unclear. Supposed we need to point the function pointer to one of 4 arithmetic functions(Plus,Mins,Multiply,Divide). how can we know which one we need to point to? We have to use the switch statement again to point the function pointer to the arithmetic functions , right?

It will be like this one**(please the comment in the code)**:

```
void Replace_A_Switch()
{
    .....................
    ..........
    //How can we know this will point to the &Minus function if we don't use the switch statement outside?
    Switch_With_Function_Pointer(2, 5, /* pointer to function 'Minus' */ &Minus);
}
```

So in summary, what is the advantages of function pointer, it always said that the function pointer a late-binding mechanism , but in this tutorial i dont see any advantage of the function pointer for late binding.
Any help are very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In brief, you need an array of function pointers that can be index by your opcode type. Since your index is `char` rather than some synthetic bytecode, that means 256 elements, and remember to cast the indices to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Given that you're coding in C++, why not use a class hierarchy with a virtual method, and let the compiler worry about the mechanics of it all?

Comment: @NPE Because, while nice abstract, such also results in a slow (relatively) VM .. it also runs counter to the purpose of exploring this approach.

Comment: A virtual function is no more or less fast or slow than a function pointer.  Function pointer is what a virtual function is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying is pretty well true, you still need to decide somewhere what function pointer to use.

What you're looking at though is a pretty simple, contrived example for explanation purpose.  It shows how you can leverage a function pointer.  In this case it might be pointlessly complicated but a real case would probably be too complicated to use to instruct in this basic concept.

The difference becomes much clearer when you've got a lot of functions that have the same switch, or a switch with subsets of the same set.  The difference is all the same though (this is also important).  In that case, why rewrite it a bunch of times?

It also opens your code for a change in how the decision is made.  Maybe you want to invert '+' and '-' for whatever reason.  Change the point where you make the pointer and all the client code catches up.

Finally, what if you don't even need to make the decision?  Instead of replacing the switch for example, what if you just wanted to do the addition version?  Obviously addition is too simple a task for this level of design, but again it's just an example.

All this is true whether you're using function pointers or a class hierarchy.  Someone has to decide what the input will be.  What these constructs do is provide you a method to compose different bits into a running program.  It also separates the part that is responsible for deciding which version of things to use from the using of those things.  There are a lot of different ways to approach that creation (see creational design patterns for some).

Comment: thanks , but can you give just an example or any link that provide such kind of example

Comment: I suppose C callbacks are real-world examples that follow the function pointer line.  I can't think of a library that uses them that I'd say is nice to use.  Pick one of the C UI APIs I guess.  There's win32, gtk, motif...to name three.

Answer (score 1):

As the tutorial states there are no advantages and the basic calculator is simply an example. The main use of function pointers is to allow the API-dev to define a function, which does something that is not known at the time the API is created.

A better example is probably [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), which takes a comparison function. Thanks to this function-pointer argument it is possible to implement the sort in a generic way. Since you could not possibly know what kind of data needs to be sorted you can't know how the `<,=,>` operators have to be implemented. Thus you expect the caller to provide a function that implements the comparison thereby avoiding this dilemma.

In general, function pointers are often useful if you want to program something in a generic way. Its use is that of function-arguments in other languages. If someone asked you to implement a simple reduce function for example, you could come up with something like this:

```
 void reduce(void *data, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
        void (*op)(void *, void *), void *res){
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < nmemb; ++i){
                        op(data, res);
                        data = (void *)((unsigned char*)data + size);
                }
        }
```

Clearly it is very advantageous over rewriting this for operations like multiply, add, and more complex ones all over again with the respective function replacing op.

Answer (score 0):

I can see how you can convert your '+', '-' etc into an `enum`, and store the 4 func pointers into an array ordered by the `enum` order. After that `arr[op]` is the function you want, just execute that.

Alternatively a `std::map<String, FuncType>` map from `+` -> `&Plus`.

Answer (score -1):

as from what i see..

the **pt2Func** is a name defined for pointer which references a function

you can see how it works in the main where it is being called 
(removed the comment to make it more readable)

```
Switch_With_Function_Pointer(2, 5, &Minus);
```

**&Minus** here is a pointer that references to your function **Minus**

this is stupid as you are calling a function to reference another function by using a pointer.
There is no benefit and it does nothing special.. its just another more complicated way to call the **Minus** function

the **Switch** function however is just a normal switch encapsulated in a function for reusability